# How do I implement a cancelable event?

Tags: c#, events

In System.ComponentModel, there's a class called CancelEventArgs which contains a Cancel member that can be set in event listeners.  The documentation on MSDN explains how to use that to cancel events from within a listener, but how do I use it to implement my own cancelable events?  Is there a way to check the Cancel member after each listener fires, or do I have to wait until after the event has fired all its listeners?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a cancel event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366684/how-to-implement-a-cancel-event-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To check each listener in turn, you need to manually get the handlers via GetInvocationList:

```
class Foo
{
    public event CancelEventHandler Bar;

    protected void OnBar()
    {
        bool cancel = false;
        CancelEventHandler handler = Bar;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            CancelEventArgs args = new CancelEventArgs(cancel);
            foreach (CancelEventHandler tmp in handler.GetInvocationList())
            {
                tmp(this, args);
                if (args.Cancel)
                {
                    cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!cancel) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code will work, is that the normal operation of a CancelEventHandler? Aren't they usually used in a BeforeX, AfterX pattern, where if anything in Before sets Canel, then X doesn't happen so AfterX doesn't get called. Why is it important to stop other listeners getting the Before event?

Comment: I also would like to know the answer to the above comment about why is it important to stop other listeners getting the Before event.

Comment: Imagine two subscribers to the same event (in the same object). One sets `cancel = true` and the second one "cancel = false". 

What do you think that would happen? The answer shows how to avoid such a situation. If at least one subscriber cancels the event, then it is cancelled. Period.