# How to implement a cancel event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, events

I know that in C#, there are several built in events that pass a parameter ("Cancel") which if set to **true** will stop further execution in the object that raised the event.

How would you implement an event where the raising object was able to keep track of a property in the EventArgs?

Here is a WinForms example of what I am trying to do: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's really easy.

```
private event _myEvent;

// ...

// Create the event args
CancelEventArgs args = new CancelEventArgs();

// Fire the event
_myEvent.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { this, args });

// Check the result when the event handler returns
if (args.Cancel)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Pretty obvious.  It's been one of those days.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @JonSeigel Do I understand it right that if there are two handlers registered and the first one sets `args.Cancel` to *true* and the second one sets `args.Cancel` to *false* then the result is `args.Cancel==false`?

Comment: @thersch: I believe so, as both handlers would be setting the value on the same object. You'd want to test it out to be certain, though.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the way that I avoid calling further subscribers once one of them asserts cancel:

```
var tmp = AutoBalanceTriggered;
if (tmp != null)
{
    var args = new CancelEventArgs();
    foreach (EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> t in tmp.GetInvocationList())
    {
        t(this, args);
        if (args.Cancel)  // a client cancelled the operation
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yet another demonstration of SO voting logic.

Answer (score 4):

What I needed was a way to stop the subscribers from receiving the event after a subscriber canceled it. In my situation I don't want the event to further propagate to the other subscribers after some subscriber canceled it.
I have implemented this using custom event handling:

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>> SubscribersList = new List<EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>>();

    public static event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> TheEvent
    {
        add {
            if (!SubscribersList.Contains(value))
            {
                SubscribersList.Add(value);
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            if (SubscribersList.Contains(value))
            {
                SubscribersList.Remove(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RaiseTheEvent(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelArgs)
    {
        foreach (EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> sub in SubscribersList)
        {
            sub(sender, cancelArgs);

            // Stop the Execution after a subscriber cancels the event
            if (cancelArgs.Cancel)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Subscriber1();
        new Subscriber2();

        Console.WriteLine("Program: Raising the event");

        CancelEventArgs cancelArgs = new CancelEventArgs();
        RaiseTheEvent(null, cancelArgs);
        if (cancelArgs.Cancel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program: The Event was Canceled");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program: The Event was NOT Canceled");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Subscriber1
{
    public Subscriber1()
    {
        Program.TheEvent += new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(program_TheEvent);
    }

    void program_TheEvent(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscriber1: in program_TheEvent");
        Console.WriteLine("Subscriber1: Canceling the event");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

public class Subscriber2
{
    public Subscriber2()
    {
        Program.TheEvent += new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(program_TheEvent);
    }

    void program_TheEvent(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscriber2: in program_TheEvent");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

1. Create an instance of CancelEventArgs (or your custom type).
2. Raise the event, passing that instance.
3. Check the Canceld property on [1].

Do you need code samples?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait the call that raise the event and then check the flag in your EventArgs (in particular CancelEventArgs).